# este codigo no abre ninguna ventana

Tags: python, tkinter

este código no arroja ningún error pero tampoco muestra la ventana, no se como proceder con este error

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Aplicacion(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs)
        
       
        
        
        
        
        self.ima=tk.PhotoImage(file="usc.gif")
        self.fonde=tk.Label(self,image=self.ima)
        self.boton1=tk.Button(self, text="Incrementar",command=self.incrementar)
        self.boton1.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=80, pady=50)
        self.boton2=tk.Button(self, text="Decrementar", command=self.decrementar)
        self.boton2.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=80, pady=50)
        self.boton3=tk.Button(self, text="1", command=self.decrementar)
        self.boton3.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=50, pady=50)
        self.boton4=tk.Button(self, text="2", command=self.decrementar)
        self.boton4.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=50, pady=50)
        
      
        root= Tk()
        root.title("My Registration Form")
        root.geometry("500x500")
        app=Aplicacion()
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Según la indentación actual, el código que abre la ventana está dentro del `__init__` de la clase app. O sea, se está creando la clase app, pero como en ninguna parte del código la inicializas, no sucede nada. La solución es sacar la parte donde se crea la ventana del `__init__`, Me explico?

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, podrias explicarme por favor a que te refieres con sacar la parte donde se crea la ventana __init__